# MySQL would not create a table if I change the name of a column

Tags: python, mysql, innodb

I am using a python code to create MySQL tables.

I am fine to create table using a specific name for my columns, but as soon as I want to change them, the tables are not created anymore.

This code bellow works without any problems

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sector_tb;

CREATE TABLE sector_tb  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sector VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    district_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE INDEX sector (sector)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
;
```

As soon as I decide to change the name of 'sector' to 'sector1' or anything else, MySQL does not create the table anymore. The code below does not create the table anymore.

```
CREATE TABLE sector_tb  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sector1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    district_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
        UNIQUE INDEX sector (sector)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
;
```

There are no errors shown while running the code.

Comment: are you running these commands sequentially or are you first dropping the table that you just made given that these both have the same table name

Comment: the first block of the code have all the 'drop' statements and the the second block of the code have all 'create' statements.

Comment: Need a `USE` statement?

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious error in second statement:
column name in the index doesn't match column name in the table.

> sector1 VARCHAR(255)
>
> UNIQUE INDEX sector (sector)

If your Python code does not report any errors, you must improve error handling.

Comment: it is an error indeed, I have been looking into this code for such a long time I cant see them anymore, thanks! aciu!

Answer (score 0):

Two options - drop the original sector_tb and run your second script or rename your column using the alter table command.